# tabular in header

Tags: tables, header-footer

I try to copy a word document in latex for the work.

[image]

With this code:

```
\documentclass{cmmse2014}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{update}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcellgapes{1pt}
\makegapedcells
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\centering
\begin{tabular}{|R{0.15\textwidth}|C{0.3\textwidth}|L{0.3\textwidth}|}
\hline 
\multirow{2}{1cm}{
\includegraphics[scale=1]{edel_logo.png}
} & col 2 &  col 3  \\ 
\cline{2-3}
& col 2&col 2\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
```

I have this result

[image]

Someone have any idea please?

thx in advance :)

Comment: Did you check the bounding box of this graphic file, with `\fbox` for instance?

Comment: Yes i did it :s

Comment: And the result?

Comment: i havent border on the outside of my figure =/

Comment: I beg your pardon, but if you write `\fbox{\includegraphics{edel_logo}}`, you have a frame around the image, at distance `\framesep`. B.t.w., can you post the logo?

Comment: yes i have a frame like you can see on the picture => https://www.dropbox.com/s/46bo04d9fznamqm/Capture.PNG?dl=0

Yes, i can :) thx for your help

https://www.dropbox.com/s/sp6llne1z8ibu2k/edel_logo.png?dl=0

Comment: The problem comes from the logo being too wide for the column width. Do you really need  `scale=1`?

Comment: Ok thx!
i must keep the same design like this file :/
http://i.stack.imgur.com/acOdw.png

Comment: I can propose you a solution in a moment, but as I do not have the cmmse2014 class, you'll have to adapt the values of the parameters for the header.

Comment: no problem you can use any class
That is so kind of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a usable example it is hard to be precise, but firstly your table looks very cramped (the word example looks to be full width, but yours is a little over 75% of the width of the text block) also adding `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}` just before the tabular will stretch it out vertically.

For the image positioning it might fit once you make the table bigger, but these things are often best positioned "by eye" so replace

```
\includegraphics[scale=1]{edel_logo.png}
```

by

```
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(1,2}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{edel_logo.png}}
\end{picture}
```

then by changing `(1,2)` to whatever you need you can move the image in any direction without affecting anything else on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do things om your code. I had to change the scaling of the image and the value of \headheight`with the`geometry` package:

```
\documentclass{article}%{cmmse2014}
\usepackage[a4paper, headheight=29pt, showframe]{geometry} \usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{update}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcellgapes{1pt}
\makegapedcells
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\centering
\begin{tabular}{|R{0.15\textwidth}|C{0.3\linewidth}|L{0.15\textwidth}|}
\hline
\multirowcell{2}[-0.3ex]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{edel_logo.png}} & col 2 & col 3 \\
\cline{2-3}
& col 2&col 2\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

thx to you two =)

```
    \documentclass{cmmse2014}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\epstopdfsetup{update}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcellgapes{1pt}
\makegapedcells
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash }b{#1}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\centering
\begin{tabular}{|R{0.15\textwidth}|C{0.65\linewidth}|L{0.15\textwidth}|}
\hline
\multirowcell{4}[-1.5ex]{\includegraphics[scale=1]{edel_logo.png}} & \multirowcell{2}[-1ex]{\LARGE{\textbf{RAPPORT PROCESS}}} & Page \thepage  sur \pageref{LastPage} \\
&  & \\
\cline{2-3}
& & Le 22/09/16\\
& & V0\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{exemple 1}
\lipsum[10]
\vfill
\end{document}
```

I must work on my template but i didnt have the problem 
[image]